# close a chrome tab with js using chrome.tab.remove

Tags: javascript, tabs

I want to click on a link and make the open chrome tab (that my page is opened in) to close. Can i use the chrome.tab.remove method to do that? Should i do anything more beforehand in order for this to work. Please advice how to do that in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
window.open('', '_self');
else
window.close();
else
win.close();
```

Comment: I haven't opened the window with window.open, so I can't close it like that.

Comment: But, window will close in this way.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, the window doesn't close.